# How do I deploy a .net core 1.1 app to IIS?

Tags: visual-studio, iis, asp.net-core

I right-clicked on the project and selected `Publish`.  I chose Folder as the target and VS 2017 published it to that folder.

I want to copy the output to IIS so that I can host it.  Which folder should IIS point to in the output?

The output contains a bunch of folders and I've tried to get IIS to point to some of them without any success.  In addition, I am not seeing a default.htm or anything traditional like that.

So where should IIS point to?

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis The steps apply to all .NET Core releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to copy whatever you see inside the screenshot under PublishOutput to a folder in web server. For example, `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\yourapplication`.

Then in IIS, `Add Website` or `Add Application` depending on your requirement.

[image]

[image]

In addition, you will need to install [.NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis#install-the-net-core-windows-server-hosting-bundle) on the web server.

Comment: The ".NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle" link you sent has the download for .net core 2.0.  I am on .net core 1.1.  Is it still the same download?

Comment: I believe it is backward comptabible with .NET 1.x. If it doesn't work, here is [DotNetCore.1.0.4_1.1.1-WindowsHosting.exe](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=844461).

Comment: That worked.  Additional piece of information here is you need to manually restart the services related to IIS.  Otherwise the install itself does not and it simply appears not to work without any meaningful error.